# Ant Custom Build and ProGuard

Tags: android, ant, proguard

I'm currently using a custom build.xml that configures ProGuard with ant, but I am receiving a few problems when running:

```
>ant clean release
```

from the command prompt.

Specifically,

1) "Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found."
2) "Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found."
3) "Problem: failed to create task or type setup" on line setup [import="false"/] where the brackets are really < and >.

My build.xml file can be found at the following link:

(http://pastebin.com/SZXesU8P)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Ryan

Answer (score 2):

Your Emma task related configuration is here:

```
<!-- Emma configuration -->
<property name="emma.dir" value="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib" />
<path id="emma.lib">
    <pathelement location="${emma.dir}/emma.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${emma.dir}/emma_ant.jar" />
</path>
<taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib" />
```

Questions:

1. Have you set the value of the property **sdk.dir**?
2. Are the emma jars located in the following locations?

   - ${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/emma.jar
   - ${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/emma_ant.jar

Since your ANT file does not set the **sdk.dir** property, I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I checked and I am referencing the SDK in local.properties file, but I don't think the build.xml is referencing either the SDK or the local.properties. I also do not have the emma jars in those locations.

Comment: @user3812290 That would explain the error alright :-)